# Build error with C API of Tesseract OCR

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, image-processing, opencv, tesseract

Using the links on [using the API](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/ocr/tesseract.html) and another [how to get the image data into a format recognizable by Tesseract](http://groups.google.com/group/tesseract-ocr/browse_thread/thread/109827382b3b82d7) I wrote the following code and added the `...tesseract/ccmain/` directory in the Include Directories of my Visual C++ project (which is already used for OpenCV].

```
#include "baseapi.h"
```

..... [OpenCV code and such]....

```
//********************* Tesseract OCR function calls *********************************************

 // create a temp buffer 
    unsigned char *buffer,*temp2; 
    buffer = new unsigned char[plate->width*plate->height*plate->nChannels]; 
    //'plate' is an IplImage*
    temp2 = buffer; 
    // pointer to imageData 
    unsigned char *temp1 = (unsigned char*) plate->imageData; 
    // copy imagedata to buffer row by row 
    for(i=0;i<plate->height;i++) 
    { 
            memcpy(temp2, temp1, plate->width*plate->nChannels); 
            // imageData jump to next line 
            temp1 = temp1 + plate->widthStep; 
            // buffer jump to next line 
            temp2 = temp2+ plate->width*plate->nChannels; 
    } 

     TessBaseAPI::InitWithLanguage(NULL, NULL, "eng", NULL, false, 0, NULL);
  char* Text = TessBaseAPI::TesseractRect( buffer, 8, 8,
                               0, 0, plate->width,plate->height);
  TessBaseAPI::End();

  printf("\n%s", Text );
```

It compiled without any error but when I try to build it there's this error for every Tesseract-related function call: "Unresolved external symbol XXXXX."
 Am I making any mistake in the linking and including of Tesseract which doesn't show up on compiling but only on building?

Any help would be great.

EDIT: these are the error messages:

```
Linking...
image.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl TessBaseAPI::End(void)" (?End@TessBaseAPI@@SAXXZ)
image.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static char * __cdecl TessBaseAPI::TesseractRect(unsigned char const *,int,int,int,int,int,int)" (?TesseractRect@TessBaseAPI@@SAPADPBEHHHHHH@Z)
image.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl TessBaseAPI::InitWithLanguage(char const *,char const *,char const *,char const *,bool,int,char * * const)" (?InitWithLanguage@TessBaseAPI@@SAHPBD000_NHQAPAD@Z)
Debug/proj.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
Error executing link.exe.
Creating browse info file...

proj.exe - 4 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Comment: ok i'm running the commandline of Tesseract by passing "tesseract image.tif text -l eng" to the shell using the system() function in stdlib.h. its a very rough thing to do, but the API is really being more trouble than its worth!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out related .LIB files and link them to your project.

Comment: found only tessdll.lib and included it. still there are the same build errors. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Could you please try following code...

```
#define TESSDLL_IMPORTS
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "baseapi.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string outfile;
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI api;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there were still build errors, I must be making some mistake in including the library. thanks anyways, though i'm using the command line arguments of Tesseract from within the program. working fine that way. the API seemed more trouble than its worth!